# Trouble with dialog layout

Tags: android, dialog, android-linearlayout

[image]

My custom dialog looks incorrect. Android cuts my buttons.

I use next layout to display this dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="280dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_top"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bottom"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Do you really want to close program?" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_orange_normal"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="@string/yes" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_lightgray_normal"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="@string/no" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

To display my custom dialog I use next code:

```
   public CustomxDialog(Context context)
{
    super(context, R.style.My_Dialog);

    root = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    title = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.title);
    super.setContentView(root);
}
```

and R.style.My_Dialog is

```
 <style name="My.Dialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_default</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In layout editor all looklikes normal. Why Android shows incorrect my dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `layout_height` for the buttons:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_orange_normal"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="@string/yes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_lightgray_normal"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:text="@string/no" />
```

`50dp` may be too large/small, play with the values until it's right.